# Equality between n number of variables

Tags: python

How do I find the largest number of repeated strings in a list of n string, and do something if this is at least j, without writing out all the possible combinations of equality?

```
j = 3
['123', '124', '123']
Desired output: FALSE becuase no element is repeated more than twice

j = 3
['123', '123', '123']
Desired output: TRUE because '123' is repeated three times

j = 2
['128', '128', '123']
Desired output: TRUE because '128' is repeated twice
```

Comment: You can use a `collections.Counter` to count things and then check if `max(counter.values())` is large enough.

Comment: `[vals.count(v) for v in vals]` will return how many times each element shows up in your list. for the last example this returns `[3, 3, 1, 3, 1]`

Comment: @piterbarg That's also working, of course, but runs in O(n^2) time, while a `Counter` is created in O(n) time. That's most likely irrelevant in this case, though :D

Comment: @NiklasMertsch good point!

Answer (score 1):

If you put your strings into a list, you can use the `list.count()` method suggested in the comments like so:

```
s_list = ['123', '123', '122']

def test_j(list_of_strings,j):
    for s in list_of_strings:
        if s_list.count(s) >= j:
            return True
    return False

print(test_j(s_list, 2))
```